# This is a question from the first round of the New Zealand Mathematical Olympiad

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

This is a question from the first round of the New Zealand Mathematical Olympiad, NZMO$1$ $2021$.

I can't understand their official solution which you can find by typing nzmo and going to the resource page.

[image: NZMO1 2021- I can't understand their official solution which you can find by typing nzmo and going to the resource page. Click this link to view the question]

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange! Since you are new, you may not be very familiar with the general etiquette of the website. In general, (1) pictures of text, such as problems or answers, should not be included as they are not searchable. It is generally expected that you type the text in the picture using mathjax. (2) You are requested to provide the solution in the post, instead of directing readers to an external website to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the problem and came to the point
$$
a^2+a(b+d)=c^2+c(b+d)
$$
from rearranging. This rearranges to
$$
a^2-c^2+(a-c)(b+d)=(a+b+c+d)(a-c)=0
$$
which gives you either $a=c$, which is not possible, or $a+b+c+d=0$.

(There is a "typo" in [the solution](https://www.mathsolympiad.org.nz/competitions/nzmo/problems/nzmo1_2021_solutions.pdf) which claims that $c>a$ but regardless of that it is possible to divide by $a-c$ as it claims, since $a>c$.)

It is sort of obvious that to get the greatest possible value, we must have $d=-2021$, and that $a$ and $c$ must both be greater than zero, and that $b=c+1$, although the solution paper provides a nice proof of each of these things.

Then finally the solution paper gives an expression for $ac$ in terms of a quadratic in $c$ alone, and it completes the square to get an entirely positive squared term, and then shows $ac$ is a maximum if $c=505$.

This solution seems perfectly OK except for the funny typo as mentioned, and there is not much you need to know to solve this except for quadratics.

Comment: Hmmm... for some reason it's just this question that doesn't make sense. I'll have a look at it again.

Comment: If it still doesn't make sense, edit your question with some more specifics about what parts you don't understand. Editing the question will bump it to the front page and more people will be able to help you.

Comment: Ok thanks very much.